# How should I make unit tests for stuff that requires sequelize?

Tags: node.js, jestjs, sequelize.js

Sequelize version: `5.21.4`

How am I supposed to write unit tests for stuff that requires sequelize? With my current setup, tests fail randomly because DB state from another test hasn't been cleared yet, even though I destroy all the rows before and after each test. It's a race condition nightmare.

I found the package `sequelize-mock`, but it hasn't been updated in 2 years. I tried it, but it doesn't quite work as a drop in replacement, and I don't even know if it's compatible with sequelize v5 (and the docs are awful).

Project: https://github.com/dyc3/opentogethertube

Example tests that fail sometimes:

- https://github.com/dyc3/opentogethertube/blob/545a07687e3d1ead5427ec7b789d595dc184af7e/tests/unit/infoextractor.spec.js#L150
- https://github.com/dyc3/opentogethertube/blob/545a07687e3d1ead5427ec7b789d595dc184af7e/tests/unit/infoextractor.spec.js#L214

Comment: Did you try https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize-mocking ?

Comment: I can't figure out how to implement sequelize-mocking into my project. The documentation is almost non existent.

Comment: Which part do you want to test? Please provide the code under test